# How to disable Python program from printing same value in list more than once?

Tags: python

So I have a program that randomly selects a certain amount of items from a list, but if a value is randomly selected I would like it to only print once, and make the program unable to print the same value twice. How do I do this?

```
import random
list = [25, 50, 75, 100]
big = int(raw_input("Big numbers: "))
y = big
b = 0
while b < y:
    j = random.choice(list)
    print j
    b += 1
```

Comment: Your code is so broken :(

Comment: Use `random.sample` or keep a set of seen items and only print if the set does not contain the item, you might want to create a `y` variable also

Answer (score 2):

`random.choice` isn't the right method to use here. Use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/random.html#random.sample) instead:

```
import random
mylist = [25, 50, 75, 100]
big = int(raw_input("Big numbers: "))
for num in random.sample(mylist, big):
    print num
```

Comment: This is great, I will rate as correct answer as soon as possible